# python printing in matrix 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, 2d

I just want to check why I can't print all the element in the matrix?
[image]

as per my knowledge this is how we write the index of this matrix

[image]

did I understand it wrongly?

the only thing that print is

[image]

please help me understand more about 2D array in matrix python. thank you

Comment: Formatting note - including the actual text of your code and error messages is far more useful than screenshots as it makes the text searchable.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data or tracebacks. Copy and paste them as text then format them as code.

Comment: `row zero column 1 -> a[0,1]`; `row one column 2 -> a[1,2]`;  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

```
x[[0,1], [3,2] ]
```

selects 2 points, `x[0,3]` and `x[1,2]`

```
x[ [[0],[1]], [3,2] ]
```

selects a (2,2) block. from rows 0 and 1, and columns 3 and 2.

Read more about numpy indexing, especially `advanced`.

### edit

```
In [190]: wt = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4]])
In [191]: wt
Out[191]: 
array([[1. , 2. , 3. , 4. ],
       [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]])
```

your first print:

```
In [192]: wt[[0,0],[1,0]]
Out[192]: array([2., 1.])
```

is the same as:

```
In [193]: wt[0,1],wt[0,0]
Out[193]: (2.0, 1.0)
```

The first list `[0,0]` is indexing rows; the second `[1,0]` columns.

first and second rows:

```
In [194]: wt[0]
Out[194]: array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
In [195]: wt[1]
Out[195]: array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4])
```

another way to select the first row:

```
In [196]: wt[0,[0,1,2,3]]
Out[196]: array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
```

the first column:

```
In [197]: wt[[0,1],0]
Out[197]: array([1. , 1.1])
In [198]: wt[:,0]
Out[198]: array([1. , 1.1])
In [199]: wt[:,[0]]          # as a 2d array
Out[199]: 
array([[1. ],
       [1.1]])
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing

documents this kind of indexing.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand what you mean :(

Comment: I added some examples closer to what you were attempting.

Comment: thanks, I understand it now , this " he first list [0,0] is indexing rows; the second [1,0] columns." is very helpful... I was just trying to print 1 with 1.1 , 2 with 2.2 , 3 with 3.3 and 4 with 4.4 ..... as in [1,1.1], [2,2.2], [3,3.3] and [4,4.4]